# C++ Inner Template Class in Separate File

Tags: c++, iterator

In organizing my c++ code, I've found that having iterators declared and implemented as inner classes, combined with all their methods, greatly reduces readability and obfuscates the code. Is there any alternative given that both the parent class and the iterator class have separate template parameters?

```
template<class A, class B>
class parent
{ 
   template<class C>
   class iter_base : iterator<std::forward_iterator>
   {
     // define all functions here.
   };
};
```

Essentially I would like to define the iterator functions in another file.

Comment: One way or another, all template definitions must be visible to the compiler at the point the templates are actually used. You can split them into two header files, and require the user to include both; or you can have one of these files include the other.

Comment: Ah, I think you are asking how to write an out-of-class definition for a member function of a member class template. It goes like this: `template<class A, class B> template<class C> void parent<A, B>::iter_base<C>::method() {}`

Comment: yes that is what I was looking for, I wasn't sure how to get the syntax quite right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of code I once wrote:

```
template <typename Btree_Type>
class btree_iterator_base;
class btree
{
public:
    using iterator = btree_iterator_base<btree>;
    using const_iterator = btree_iterator_base<const btree>;

private:
    template <typename Btree_Type>
    friend class btree_iterator_base;
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    iterator lower_bound(key_type key);
    const_iterator lower_bound(key_type key) const;
    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type & value);
    // and so on
};

template <typename Btree_Type>
class btree_iterator_base
{
public:
    using value_type = btree::value_type;
    friend class btree;
    btree_iterator_base() : /* initializers */ { }

    // more code
private:
    // to be called from btree::begin() and so on
    btree_iterator_base(leaf_ptr leaf, uint16_t entry_in_leaf)
    {
        // code
    }
    // more code
};

auto btree::begin() -> iterator
{
    leaf_ptr ptr(*this, header().m_first_leaf);
    return iterator(ptr, 0);
}
```

I should  have inherited from std::iterator, but this was a short 
experimental code, and I got sloppy.

I have a similarly structured code for a compressed set of int.